# How do I set a linear gradient over a background image in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, background-image, linear-gradients

I have been trying for over an hour and this is the only thing I can come up with.  I built the app with CRA so I have to keep the image in the img folder. I am new to React some I am at a lost here for what to do/

```
    import NavBar from "./NavBar";
    // import SocialMedia from "../socialmedia/SocialMedia";
    import classes from './MainView.module.css';
    import background from '../../img/pic2.jpg';
    
    
    
    function MainView() {
        const style = {
            backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( rgba(8, 8, 37, 0.85), rgba(0, 15, 80, 0.675)), url("${background}")`
        };
    
        return (
            <>
                <NavBar />
                <section style={{ style }}
                    className={classes.top}>
                    <div>
                        <p>My Name</p>
                        <p>Full Stack Web Developer</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
                {/* <SocialMedia /> */}
            </>
        )
    }
    
    export default MainView;






@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Trispace&display=swap');

.top {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell the code is *mostly* correct. The one issue I see is with how you pass/set the `style` prop. You are passing an object with a `style` property with the CSS rules nested deeper.

```
<section
  style={{ style }} // <-- style properties nested too deeply!
  className={classes.top}
>
  ...
</section>
```

This results in a `style` prop that looks more like this:

```
{
  style: {
    backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( rgba(8, 8, 37, 0.85), rgba(0, 15, 80, 0.675)), url("${background}")`,
  }
}
```

when you just want:

```
{
  backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( rgba(8, 8, 37, 0.85), rgba(0, 15, 80, 0.675)), url("${background}")`
}
```

The solution is to just pass `style` as the prop value:

```
style={style}
```

or spread the `style` object into the `style` prop:

```
style={{ ...style }}
```

I suggest the former.

Full example:

```
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
// import SocialMedia from "../socialmedia/SocialMedia";
import classes from './MainView.module.css';
import background from '../../img/pic2.jpg';

function MainView() {
  const style = {
    backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( rgba(8, 8, 37, 0.85), rgba(0, 15, 80, 0.675)), url("${background}")`
  };

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <section
        style={style} // <-- pass the style object directly
        className={classes.top}
      >
        <div>
          <p>My Name</p>
          <p>Full Stack Web Developer</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      {/* <SocialMedia /> */}
    </>
  )
}

export default MainView;
```